# Map positive real line to $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am looking for a function (ideally a bijection) $f(x)$ that maps the unit interval to the positive real numbers. The function should fulfill the following restrictions

1. $\text{lim}_{x\rightarrow0} f(x) \rightarrow 0$
2. $f(0.5) = 1$
3. $\text{lim}_{x\rightarrow1} f(x) \rightarrow \infty$

I've been playing around with variants of $\frac{x}{1+x}$ without success. It's easy to get restrictions 1 and 3 right, but I couldn't manage to find a solution that works without a ''replacement'' solution like the top answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3895333/bijection-that-maps-1-infty-to-0-1).

Comment: Are you looking for something like $\tan(\frac{\pi}2 x)$?

Comment: Do you mean $(0, 1)$ rather than $[0, 1]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$? This function maps the interval $(0,1)$ to $(0,\infty)$ and satisfies your three requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

If $f(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)=\infty$, then $g_k(x)=f(x)+kx$ (where $k\geq 0$) also satisfies those constraints. You can then just massage $k$ to ensure that $g_k(\frac 12)=1$

Coincidentally, I also stumbled upon $f(x)=-(1+\frac{1}{x-1})$ which fits the bill without needing that extra step.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the limits you are talking about are deleted limits (otherwise, this is just impossible).

With that in mind, here are some hints:

1. You can just have $f$ be identity on $(0,1/2)$; this deals with the first requirement.
2. You have no choice with $f(1/2)=1$. You might as well keep going and have $f(0)=2$, $f(1)=3$. You are left with finding a bijection $(1/2,1)\to (1/2,+\infty)\setminus \{1,2,3\}$.
3. Start with a bijection $(1/2,1)\to (1/2,+\infty)$, and then compose it with a bijection $(1/2,+\infty)\to (1/2,+\infty)\setminus \{1,2,3\}$.